# How to copy files from ipfs using git annex?

Tags: git, ipfs, git-annex

I've cloned Git repository with files stored in local ipfs, I've initialized ipfs special remote, however I cannot download files stored in there.

I've run: `git annex copy --from ipfs` as suggested in this [page](https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/ipfs/), but the files aren't downloaded. It's like git-annex doesn't see them there.

---

Here is my setup (this part works):

1. I've local IPFS Deamon running (`ipfs init; ipfs daemon`).
2. I've installed [Git Annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) (Apt/Brew install git-annex).
3. Installed ipfs remote script (as per [git-annex/special remotes/ipfs](https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/ipfs/) page):

   ```
   mkdir -v ~/bin
   wget -O ~/bin/git-annex-remote-ipfs https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/external/git-annex-remote-ipfs
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
   ```
4. I've created a new repo (`mkdir test01 && cd test01 && git init`).
5. I've committed a regular file (`touch README.md; git add README.md; git commit -m'Initial commit' README.md`).
6. I've initialized git-annex (`git annex init`).
7. I've initialized annex remote (`git annex initremote ipfs type=external externaltype=ipfs encryption=none`).
8. I've committed ipfs file (`echo test > ipfs-file.txt; git annex add ipfs-file.txt; git commit -m'Adds ipfs file' ipfs-file.txt`).
9. Copied to local ipfs object store (`git annex copy --to ipfs`).
10. Synchronize local repository with remotes (`git annex sync ipfs`). I'm not sure if this is needed.
11. I've confirmed file is at ipfs having ipfs address with CID assigned (`git annex whereis ipfs-file.txt`).
12. `git annex list` outputs `X__X ipfs-file.txt` additionally confirming the file is at ipfs storage.

Cloning into new repo and downloading files from ipfs (this part doesn't work):

1. Created another empty repo (`mkdir ../test02 && cd ../test02 && git init`).
2. Pulled files from the previous repo (`git pull ../test01`).
3. Now `ipfs-file.txt` is a symbolic link to non-existing file (`ls -la ipfs-file.txt`).
4. I've initialized git-annex in the new repo (`git annex init`).
5. I've initialized annex remote (`git annex initremote ipfs type=external externaltype=ipfs encryption=none`).
6. Enabled ipfs remote (`git annex enableremote ipfs`). I don't think it's needed.
7. I did sync (`git annex sync ipfs`). I'm not sure if this is needed.
8. I've run: `git annex copy --from ipfs`, **this doesn't do anything**. I expect it to copy the files from ipfs remote.

I've run the following commands:

```
% git annex whereis ipfs-file.txt
whereis ipfs-file.txt (0 copies) failed
whereis: 1 failed

% git annex list                 
here
|web
||bittorrent
|||ipfs
||||
____ ipfs-file.txt
```

which suggest the file isn't present at ipfs remote (missing `X`), however it was in the 1st repository.

I've run `git annex copy --from ipfs -d` (with debug), but `git-annex-remote-ipfs` script
isn't even called like it does on `--to ipfs`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could use `git annex whereis` to look up the ipfs address of the file  in the original repository (test01) to obtain the IPFS CID for the file.

```
git annex whereis ipfs-file.txt
```

Then, in the new repository (test02), use the `git annex registerurl` command with the obtained IPFS CID.

```
git annex registerurl ipfs-file.txt /ipfs/Qm...
```

That should allow you to run `git annex copy --from ipfs` in the new repository (`test02`) and download the file.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I had to do: `git annex registerurl SHA256E-s5--f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2.txt ipfs:QmeomffUNfmQy76CQGy9NdmqEnnHU9soCexBnGU3ezPHVH` (to accept the syntax), but still it it doesn't know `whereis` the file. I've added `set -ex` to the `git-annex-remote-ipfs` script, it gives me more output when running `git annex`, but it isn't much helpful. It's possible `git-annex-remote-ipfs` needs some fixing.

Comment: OK, I hope it will be fixed.